# Outdated code from a tutorial. Can't figure it out

Tags: pygame, python-3.7

I was following a tutorial about how to 3D render objects in pygame. However it seems that the code is outdated and I don't know how to fix it.

I've spent quite a bit of time looking for the solution, but to no avail, as I don't know what I'm looking for.

```py
def rotateX(self, (cx,cy,cz), radians):
    for node in self.nodes:
        y      = node.y - cy
        z      = node.z - cz
        d      = math.hypot(y, z)
        theta  = math.atan2(y, z) + radians
        node.z = cz + d * math.cos(theta)
        node.y = cy + d * math.sin(theta)
```

It is supposed to show me a game window with a cube that I can move around and such, but instead it throws me an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wireframe
  File "C:\Users\elee4018\Desktop\Python\pyGame01\wireframe.py", line 34
    def scale(self, (centre_x, centre_y), scale):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that your error message isn't pointing to the code you've pasted (`def scale` vs `def rotateX`). They share the same issue.

It's an older Python2 syntax. Simply just replace it with `rotateX(self, cx, cy, cz, radians)` or `rotateX(self, axies, radians)` and add a line that does `cx, cy, cz = axies` at the start of the function. Either way, Python3 simply just doesn't take a tuple expansion by default. At least not in this way.

So either do:

```
def rotateX(self, cx, cy, cz, radians):
    for node in self.nodes:
        y      = node.y - cy
        z      = node.z - cz
        d      = math.hypot(y, z)
        theta  = math.atan2(y, z) + radians
        node.z = cz + d * math.cos(theta)
        node.y = cy + d * math.sin(theta)
```

And make sure you update the call to the `rotateX` function, or you could do:

```
def rotateX(self, axies, radians):
    cx, cy, cz = axies
    for node in self.nodes:
        y      = node.y - cy
        z      = node.z - cz
        d      = math.hypot(y, z)
        theta  = math.atan2(y, z) + radians
        node.z = cz + d * math.cos(theta)
        node.y = cy + d * math.sin(theta)
```

And you shouldn't need to update the call to the function in any way. There's probably a neater way to do the same thing as Python2 did. But I have never needed or used it. But this should solve your problem at least.

Oh, and submit a issue report to Pygame. They should be aware or instructed if the instructions are off/old.